# Access global configuration in Alfresco evaluator

Tags: configuration, global, alfresco, evaluator

I am wondering if it's possible to access global configuration variables when defining an evaluator?

i.e. 
I define a title of a GROUP in the global configuration.
The evaluator should read the value of that group and render the action depending on the group.

I don't want to hard-code the group, I want to leave a possibility to change it without rebuilding the module.

Can someone tell me weather it's possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by global configuration?

Comment: By global configuration I mean `web-scripts-config-custom.xml` or any of the mentioned in [link](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/api-ws-obj-config.html) @KrutikJayswal

Comment: Isn't that going the wrong way round? Normally you'd define your configuration for the evaluation in the bean definition of it, and inject those into evaluator. So, value -> config -> bean -> evaluator, not evaluator -> fetch config -> value

Comment: still i didn't get you question.